# GX 18 upgrade de licencias y de GxServer

Tags: genexus

Tengo licencias para trabajar con Gx17 y con Gxserver 17. Quiero empezar a trabajar con Gx18, necesito actualizar las licencias, lo que necesito saber es si también puedo actualizar el gxserver o debe generar una nueva instancia para que no dejen de funcionar las kb que actualmente tengo en gx17.

Alguien tiene un instructivo con los pasos a seguir?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más seguro es instalar una nueva instancia y luego ir moviendo las KBS con el GXSSM. (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18169,GeneXus+Server+Storage+Migrator+Utility).
Otra posibilidad es directamente desconectarlas del server V17 e enviarlas al de V18, pero ahi perdés la historia que está en el GXServer porque lo que se manda es la working copy no lo que está en el server.

Respecto a las licencias: si ambas instancias están en la misma máquina es la misma licencia (tenés que tener la de V18 que es backward compatible). Notar que tiene que usar el apppool tiene que usar el mismo identity (normalmente: Local System).

Podrías directamente actualizar la instancia a V18 y pedir la clave, pero eso implica que todas las KBs se convertirán a V18 a la vez, todos los desarrolladores tienen que pasar a usar V18, etc. Digamos que no hay un modo fácil de "volver atrás", por eso lo más recomendable es ir convirtiendo de a KB o grupo de desarrolladores.

De pronto esta guia te sirve: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21510,GeneXus+Server+Setup